# Writing a php array for use as google charts data

Tags: php, google-api

I want to display table data on a google geo chart and need help writing an array to plug into the google api.

I'm using php to gather the table info and put it in an array. I need help building the array.

```
$st = $con->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM table' );
$st->execute();
$list = array();
while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  $list[] = $row;
}
?>
```

And here is where the array is the code for inserting the array in the google charts api.
As you can see it is expecting the data to be as follows.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['State', 'Freight'],
  ['OK', 150],
  ['KS', 250],
  ['TX', 250],
  ['AR', 250],
  ['NM', 250],
  ['NE', 250]
]);
```

So, should i put php in the javascript and loop echo, the rows results?
Or should i put the php in a separate file and make an ajax request?
If i do an ajax request, is the api expecting xml or json?

Comment: Looks like the Google chart is expecting an array of json objects? If that is the case the data type json can be specified in the AJAX request. On the PHP side make an array of arrays. do json_encode() iirc and return data to client.

Comment: I'm almost there. This is a great suggestion

Comment: Won't give you the answer but I'll point you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and quickest method is just to loop through the array as you usually would. Ex:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Freight'],
    <?php foreach($list as $listItem): ?>
        ['<?= $listItem['state'] ?>', <?= $listItem['freight'] ?>],
    <?php endfor; ?>
]);
```